# To read pdf in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, pdf, store

I want to read pdf file and i want to store it's detail in my database.
But i could not read pdf file & store it in sql database in asp.net using c#. So, please give me a solution if anyone knows...

Very very thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to effectively parse the contents of the PDF file, you may want to use a PDF management library such as [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/). Otherwise, you could just store the raw file contents using a binary field in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Please see these article, May be these will help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/showcase/TallComponents.asp

Else if you can purchase adobe toolkit for this then it will very easy for you to play with PDF.